# Cygwin cannot cat the content of symlink on Win7 if not in the current directory

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, symlink

I've installed 64-bit Cygwin on my Windows 7 host OS. I added `winsymlinks:nativestrict` to the environment of CYGWIN to create Windows native symlink.
I have a symlink here, the output of `ls -l .git/hooks/commit-msg` is

```
.git/hooks/commit-msg -> ../../../../../repo/hooks/commit-msg
```

However, when I try to access this file, for example with `cat` or `diff`, the output of `cat .git/hooks/commit-msg`:

```
cat: .git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory
```

If I go to the directory of .git/hooks, the `cat` again, it works fine.

This problem prevents me from doing `repo upload`.

Comment: It seems that the directory `hooks` is a symlink too. Only if Cygwin can follow `hooks` first, then the symlink `../../../../../` is a right place. Otherwise, there's no `../../../../../` relative to the currently directory location.

Comment: It is confirmed as a Cygwin problem. It's fixed in 2014-04-16 snapshot.